# The Derivative of $y=x^2$ with respect to $\ln x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the derivatives of $y$$=$$x^2$ with respect to $\ln x.$

Comment: I do my calc teacher isn't here for the week and the teacher that is here can't help me I tried getting help on Khan Academy but I couldn't find a video that could help me

Comment: Im trying to learn how to do it so can someone take me step by step on the problem it would be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $f(x)=x^2$ takes you from$ x$ to $x^2$. However you want a function that takes you from $ln(x)$ to $x^2$. You can find this function by taking the composition of two functions.

To do this first find a function that takes you from $ln(x)$ to $x$

( $e^x$ )( because $e^{lnx}=x$)

and then apply the function $x^2$ to go from $x$ to $x^2$.

You can use the chain rule to find the derivative of this big function with respect to lnx (Kahn has videos on the chain rule)

let $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=x^2$ then $g(f(ln(x))= x^2$ and using the chain rule the derivative of $g(f(x))$ is $f'(x)*g'(f(x)$. so its $e^x*2e^x$. which is $2e^{2x}$

Answer (score 8):

Hint:  let $u=\ln x$.  You are looking for $\frac {dy}{du}$.  This is an application of the fact that $\frac {dy}{du}=\frac {dy}{dx}\frac {dx}{du}$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$y=x^2\implies\log y=\log x^2=2\log|x|\ldots$$